# Typed Indexing variable is not of the same type as the object being indexed

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

I have a slightly complex object that has typed keys on the top-most level of the object, as well as the deepest level of the object, and I can't seem to be able to index the second typed keys of the object.

This is my object and my interfaces (simplified):

```
const obj = {
  keyA: {
    variants: {
      "0": false,
      "1": false
    }
  },
  keyB: {
    variants: {
      "0-0": false,
      "0-1": false
    }
  }
}

type Obj = typeof obj;
type ObjKeys = keyof Obj;
type ObjVariants<T extends ObjKeys> = Obj[T]["variants"];
```

and this is the function that cannot properly index `selectedKeys.variant` using `defaultVariant`.

```
function getVariant<T extends ObjKeys>(key: T, defaultVariant: keyof ObjVariants<T>) {
  const selectedKey = obj[key];
  const selectedVariant = selectedKey.variants[defaultVariant];
}
```

The error I get is:

```
Type 'keyof { keyA: { variants: { 0: boolean; 1: boolean; }; }; keyB: { variants: { "0-0": boolean; "0-1": boolean; }; }; }[T]["variants"]' cannot be used to index type '{ 0: boolean; 1: boolean; } | { "0-0": boolean; "0-1": boolean; }'.(2536)
```

It seems to be related to these two issues: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21760 and https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36631
But I'm not sure that the "workaround" for the second one works for me, I feel like I'm missing something

Here's the link to the playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=65&pc=3#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvAUDGBrApgJ4CCAXBtjjAG4CGATgJa1hQTlZVUBEADN+QBmtADYR8AGkpduARgExhY-NJgBfSmqk4ChAEIdVdJizaGuOPgFp+Q0eO0Xr8u8tUacGjZiiEADvgwAPJIqDC+ASCCcEgA3D7+gSGIANJEEGG6UcFxCQE5iABqDMysEAA8ACow+AAeUPhgACYZyWmEEAB8YckA2pUAur3cxqVs3APxmJiCAK5gwFCM4DAA5vhQxSasVTX1jS0F7V0AFLrklRIwTfjCsyKbJabkWdHJW2MVlZ0AlBQ4oEgsHEInwi3wTXaYQQiF6ukmlEB0BgILBDSaH1MYVR4MhRAAdKNTBBejc7g9MawERogA

Has anyone else encountered something similar/has a suggested workaround?

PD: I tried adding a strict type to `obj` and found the same result as using `typeof obj`.

Comment: "T extends ObjKeys" does not mean that T could be "keyA" **XOR** "keyB": T could be "keyA"|"keyB" as well because "keyA"|"keyB" in fact extends ObjKeys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like behavior by design, or in other words design limitation. Such function is hard to be type safe as we can pass subtypes also. For example `T extends ObjKeys` covers also the union `keyA | keyB`, it means that this constraint cannot assume it will be one of variants.

In order to totally set the constraint we can go into following approach:

```
function getVariant
<O extends { [K in K1]: { variants: { [KK in K2]: Obj[K1]["variants"][KK] } } }
, K1 extends keyof Obj
, K2 extends keyof Obj[K1]["variants"]>
  (o: O, key: K1, defaultVariant: K2) {
  const selectedKey = o[key].variants;
  const selectedVariant = selectedKey[defaultVariant];
}
// using
getVariant(obj, 'keyA', '0')
```

As you can see I made additional parameter in order to narrow the type for keys `K1` and `K2`. The most important line is `{ [K in K1]: { variants: { [KK in K2]: Obj[K1]["variants"][KK] } } }`. It means that we deal with type which covers both keys, but still the definition is compatible with our `obj` type.

We can still be using `obj` as a outside constant, but then we need to use type assertion:

```
function getVariant<K1 extends keyof Obj, K2 extends keyof Obj[K1]["variants"]>
  (key: K1, defaultVariant: K2) {
  let _obj = obj as { [K in K1]: { variants: { [KK in K2]: Obj[K1]["variants"][KK] } } };
  const selectedKey = _obj[key].variants;
  const selectedVariant = selectedKey[defaultVariant];
}
// using
getVariant('keyA', '0')
```

Why this works? It works because we statically set the type with exact types we have/will have. If we say `T extends A` it doesn't mean T is A, it doesn't mean also that T is some variant of A. By saying `T extends A` we narrow, restrict the type `T` to be assignable to `A`, therefor we are not strict. By making type `{[K in T]: X}, T extends Y` we strictly define that the type will have exact key of `T`, and it will be strictly one type from the possible assignable types to `Y`. Such strict definition is equal to setting static value like `Obj['keyA']`.

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you very much. I have one more small question, this is the type of `getVariant` when I haven't added the first parameter: `getVariant(key: "keyA" | "keyB", defaultVariant: never): void`. After adding the key, variant autocomplete successfully (Amazing!), I was wondering if you could briefly explain how `defaultVariant` becomes `never` initially. Thank you for your response!

Comment: Can you send me some Playground? Its hard to get your question.

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit late to the party, but the following generalization could solve the problem:

```
type KeyOf<T> = keyof T;

function getVariant<
  O extends { [K in KeyOf<O>]: { variants: O[K]["variants"] } },
  K extends KeyOf<O>,
  V extends KeyOf<O[K]["variants"]>,
>(obj: O, key: K, variant: V): O[K]["variants"][V] {
  return obj[key].variants[variant];
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.2&ssl=9&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIHkBmAeAKgPigXiga3gHsko0AoMpAVwDsBjYAS0JqgHMJgA1AQwCdGPGsBRkoUBFAgAPYBBoATAM5QA3lADaMKI1ZxEqBBgC6ALjVQAbv0HCl5hFuMaARNYFDgSl8agBffwAaMVgpWXllWHhkFCNg8S4wuUUVfRjHGGc3G09vYwxgjAAKQgAjACsHQPx4cxhq91tgcy4ASgcnV0bcnw0uX1UQvk4qPlYy8o0CEGMAOm67DQXgYwBuMj8KMgB6bag5JWAKOhZDqAmcNRDpgEFzQfFxZfsrx8eXAAYXcyQeABslBB4m8oC4AIzfKC-AFAkJvFwnAC2iJYkOAfCosLefmBOOu8AAQvc4VYcnZiSDQR8ALRfczozHA+E0iE-f6ApnvJEomiQ6Eckl48R4gI8FQnGiHdZbCVnSxgy4cbhk4AlCrVFy3Fwar6tda7EEAPQA-GRZcArAAmRWcXgeYRq8oa6YE7VU2kuPU7PZvE1m04WywAZhtyvtqom1QAsjxgAALWZ8IQKQiIoqtKBYD6zACsUGNoK1UHMmsJboRqZ5nv1PseJqAA)